# Как правильно перенести слова "предусмотрено", "безопасный"?

Tags: фонетика

Интересен именно первый слог:

пре-дусмотрено, без-опасный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пре-дусмотрено, без-опасный и бе-зопасный. 
Сейчас правила переносов весьма либеральны, ориентироапны в основном на слоговую структуру слова. Тем не менее последний случай считается наименее удачным. 
Что касается слова "предусмотрено" то здесь сложно выделить приставку (на самом деле их две: пред- и -у-, но они прочно слились воедино), поэтому перенос, полагаю, стоит осуществлять по принципу слогоделения.

Вообще правила переносов - здесь.
http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=perenos